# Why the LSTM can't reduce the loss

Tags: tensorflow, keras, lstm, lm, stock

i'm using lstm to train a model to predict the stock price, i used the many to one mode like this:

```
                                    O 
                                    | 
                              O O O O 
                              | | | | 
                              O O O O
```

and i used keras framework to build the network, but it seems the NN can't be build up easily...

here is my lstm NN source code of python:

```
def lstm_rls(num_in,num_out=1, batch_size=128, step=1,dim=1):
    model = Sequential()
    
    model.add(LSTM(
        1024,
        input_shape=(step, num_in),
        return_sequences=True))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))
    
    model.add(LSTM(
        512,
        return_sequences=False))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))
    
    model.add(Dense(1))
    model.add(Activation('linear'))
    model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='rmsprop')
    return model
```

i trained about 512 epochs, but the loss is always around the 7

> Epoch 1/512
>
> 3968/3968 [==============================] - 4s 978us/step - loss: 48.6274
>
> Epoch 2/512
>
> 3968/3968 [==============================] - 1s 220us/step - loss: 11.1913
>
> Epoch 3/512
>
> 3968/3968 [==============================] - 1s 221us/step - loss: 6.8059
>
> Epoch 4/512
>
> 3968/3968 [==============================] - 1s 220us/step - loss: 6.7905
>
> Epoch 5/512
>
> 3968/3968 [==============================] - 1s 221us/step - loss: 6.8151
>
> Epoch 6/512
>
> 3968/3968 [==============================] - 1s 219us/step - loss: 6.7907
>
> Epoch 7/512
>
> 3968/3968 [==============================] - 1s 220us/step - loss: 6.8060
>
> Epoch 8/512
>
> 3968/3968 [==============================] - 1s 221us/step - loss: 6.7824

...
...
...

> Epoch 509/512
>
> 3968/3968 [==============================] - 1s 222us/step - loss: 6.7807
>
> Epoch 510/512
>
> 3968/3968 [==============================] - 1s 223us/step - loss: 6.8199
>
> Epoch 511/512
>
> 3968/3968 [==============================] - 1s 222us/step - loss: 6.7726
>
> Epoch 512/512
>
> 3968/3968 [==============================] - 1s 222us/step - loss: 6.7715

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have had your problem for image captioning(I had four Gpu tesla k20). It take long time to train the LSTM(about several day). I think your problem is natural. One way that I used was increasing batch size. In other side, increasing of batch size is relative with performance and memory usage.

Comment: so do you mean i need to increase the epoch of training ? maybe several days later i can got a good model ?

Comment: No, my mean is about your batch_size that is 128. You can try to increase that. For example: 512 if memory be enough. Answer of your question is yes. Anyway, you must be patience in this way.

Comment: There are other things you can do, you should for instance normalize your data if you have not allready done so, and you can try with different activation functions for your layers. (default for LSTM is tanh)

Comment: @Ali Mahdavi  thank you for your advise, i used the batch size 2048 to increase the memory usage up to 90%, but after 2000 epoches, the loss still around 7....

Comment: @VegardKT   how to do the instance normalize in keras, is there any examples ?

Comment: There are different ways of scaling your data, i would recomend scaling either between 0 and 1 or -1 and 1. see : http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler.html

Comment: @VegardKT  greate, it worked, at least the loss is less than 0.1 in 512 epochs!

Comment: Yes your loss will naturally decrease greatly when you are normalizing data because your values was probably much higher than 1. This doesnt nescessarily mean that your model has improved as muc hthough, just so you are aware. (What im trying to say is that you cannot directly compare your loss before and after normalizing)

Comment: @VegardKT  i used batch normalize cause keras only supply this kind of normalizing, i have a doubt, train data is changed when normalize, so it that will influence the prediction of test data?

Answer (score 0):

Today I watched one lecture about debugging tips. It said that one way that you can analysis your code is:
Verify that object function decreases on small training set, not all at first time.

Comment: which lecture, can you share it to me, i'm a newer in this area.^o^